# If a European investor goes long or short the US ultrabond future, are they taking any forex risk or is it all interest rate risk?

Tags: bonds, futures

(The Ultrabond future is a bet on the price of 30-year US treasury bonds, which are dollar denominated.)

Answer (score 1):

For a futures position with typical margin, the risk is *almost entirely* interest rate risk. This is because the interest rate risk is leveraged but the forex risk is not (another way to look at it: the leverage is achieved by effectively borrowing in USD). If the bond futures price in USD is unchanged but USD declines 1% relative to EUR, the investor has lost 1% on whatever margin deposit was made. On the other hand, if the bond futures price in USD declines 1%, the investor has lost much more than 1% on the margin deposit (approximately 20% loss on minimum margin).

Comment: Great answer - a simple example showing exact calculations of both scenarios with an assumed rate of leverage could improve it even further.